# Rearanging numpy array without memory error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, out-of-memory

I am currently trying to run a Monte Carlo simulation for which I would need more than 5,000,000 iterations (the outputs are still not consistent at that point).

When I try and run it for more than 5 million however I get a memory error when re-arranging my array to obtain the data sorted in a way I can easily plot it.
the error occurs at

```
np.array([np.array([run_single_regression(inputs) for  x in xrange(iterations)])]).transpose()
```

This is the function I run:

```
def Monte_Carlo_regressions(filename, iterations, do_plot = False):
    inputs = data_assignment_regression(filename)
    total_pow, total_energy = np.array([np.array([run_single_regression(inputs) for  x in xrange(iterations)])]).transpose()
    if do_plot:
        plot(total_pow, 'Total Power Capacity (GW)')
        plot(total_energy, 'Total Energy Storage Capacity (TWh)')
    return total_pow.mean(0), total_pow.std(0), total_energy.mean(0), total_energy.std(0)
```

The `data_assignment_regression(filename)` function returns a set of 1D arrays assigned to the `inputs`.

The `run_single_regression(inputs)` function estimates the power and energy outputs for that iteration and return a numpy array containing the power and energy for that iteration.

How can I avoid the memory error ?  Is there a way I could re-arrange the array without having to store all the value ?

Comment: There are a few things happening on that line. Which one throws the error? For example, does `[run_single_regression(inputs) for  x in xrange(iterations)]` already throw an error? If this is where the trouble is, consider not using Python list iterator here, but rather have a function that takes the number of iterations as a argument and returns a NumPy array with the results.

Comment: Hi zaq, there used to  be an error here, but I replaced range with xrange and it now passes that point, which makes me think the bottleneck is further down the line

Comment: So where is it, the first array constructor or the second, or transpose?